# xlwings output to iterative cell range

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwings, vba

I have a large dataset that I do not have direct access to and am trying to convert the data headers into column headings using Python and then returning it back to Excel.

I have created the function to do this and it works but I have hit a snag. What I want the Excel VBA to do is loop down the range and if the cell's value matches the criteria call the Python function and return the resulting list items in the columns moving across from the original cell.  For example:

`A1` holds the string to format, the functions returns `B1`, `C1`, `D1`, and so on. I can only get this to work if I hard code `B1`, `C1`, `D1`, etc.

Is there a way to do this via the `get_address()` range method? I think I can then use the `offset()` method but am not sure.

Comment: If I understand you right, you should be able to loop through your Range by using index notation: `Range((i,j))`. Note that it will be more efficient to read in the whole range into Python at once, then do all the logic and write out the result array at once instead of looping through each cell.

Comment: @FelixZumstein hi Felix. You're probably right except I don't know how to read in the whole range and process it through in Python and churn it back to Excel. I thought about doing that first but sending it to a CSV file but didn't know how to do that either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may use the offset method, and do something like the below:

```
for x in range(1, 11): #loop through a range
if Range('A' + str(x)).value == 5: #to match your own criterion
    Range('A' + str(x)).offset(0, 1).value = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'] #the returns of your own function
```

Comment: Thanks @DanEng that helped get me off the ground. My loop now returns the right info just on every line rather than just the one matching the condition. I tried pasting the code but it made the comment too big.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I've got this to work now and I'm super excited about the future possibilities for Python, xlwings and Excel.

My problem was simple once I got the looping through the range sorted (which incidentally was handily imported as each row per element rather than each cell). I had declared my list outside of the function and so was not reset each time the true condition was met. It was getting very frustrating watching my cells fill with the same values time after time. Simple once you know how :)